# Configure play framework to work with log4j2

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

Is it possible to configure Play framework so instead of writing its logs using logback, it will work with log4j2?

The issue is that our backend uses log4j2 and we don't want to have two different log configurations in our system.

I'll appreciate your help.

Nadav

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, this should be a comment rather than an answer but I don't have enough rep.

There are a couple of open [issues](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3747) with switching out logback from Play at present.

Answer (score 1):

Since Play 2.5, alternative logging frameworks can be configured: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SettingsLogger#Using-a-Custom-Logging-Framework